# creating a schema, one of its fields include an objectId that refers to the other schema objectId, and a string

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Here is the code. The following and follower are not able to work. In other words, I can't push an object like `{"user1", objectId1}` to these two arrays.
Is allowed to have a field that includes both an object Id, and a string name?
I appreciate your help.

> ```
> The error is: 
>    { CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ userId: '594ad9106f636d4e244d1f11', username: 'aa' }" at path "followers"
> ```

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: {type: String, unique: true},
        password: String,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        roles: [{
            type: String, default: 'USER', enum: ['USER', 'ADMIN']
        }],
        facebook: {
            id: String,
            token: String
        },
        email: String,
        phone: String,
        websites: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ProjectWebsiteModel"}],
        dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        followings: [{username: String, type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ProjectUsereModel"}],
        followers:  [{username: String, type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ProjectUsereModel"}]

}, {collection: "projectuser"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
followings: [{
    username: String, 
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "ProjectUsereModel"
    }
}],
followers:  [{
    username: String,
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "ProjectUsereModel"
    }
}]
```

...so your 'following' and 'followers' arrays will contain objects with the properties 'username' and 'id'.

Comment: I have to say: Thank you

Comment: No problem. Are you able to make this the accepted answer?